# Launch or appear a UIViewController when receiving a phone call with iOS CallKit

Tags: ios, phone-call, callkit

In iOS phone application I want to appear or launch a UIViewController when receiving a phone call an force it to be on top of the phone call view.
Is this possible using the iOS 10 CallKit, if not is there any other way to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. When there is a CallKit incoming call screen, it shows on top of your app.